# implement a flowchart as a program

Tags: python, spyder, implementation, interactive, flowchart

I have to implement a flowchart as a program that has five or more questions...
I have, I think, successfully asked the first question with three possible outcomes. How do I then ask a question off of that outcome?!

Off of the end of yes and maybe, I then want to go on to ask the person to input the answers 'two' or 'for'.. how do I combine the functions print and input to do this?

I hope this makes sense... its confusing to explain!

```
#start
horse_input=input('you a horse?')
if horse_input =='yes':
   print ('how many legs do you have?')
elif horse_input == 'maybe':
    print('how many legs do you have?')
if[] =='two':
   print("you're not a horse")
elif horse_input=='no':
   print ("not a horse")
```

#not sure how to ask for user input 'two' or 'four'
my question is what goes in that place with the square brackets to get an answer for the question to my question...?!

Comment: Use another `input(...)`?

Comment: where do I put this? because I want the input to stem off of how many legs do you walk on without reprinting it.... how do I ask for user input off of that?!